# Show that there are $A,B$ with $\mathcal{P}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:Ax≤\mathbf{1},\;Bx≤\mathbf{0} \}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, polyhedra

$\mathcal{P}$ is a polyhedron, such that $\mathbf{0}\in\mathcal{P}$. Show that there are Matrices $A,B$ with:
$$\mathcal{P}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:Ax≤\mathbf{1},\;Bx≤\mathbf{0} \}$$There seems to be so little to go with, that I don't really know how to go about answering this question. I would appreciate someone helping me with this, either through hints or a full solution.

Comment: How do you define a polyhedron?

Comment: Start with a simple case: the cube $[-1,1]^3$. This can be described as the set $$\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3\mid x \le 1, x \ge -1, y \le 1, y\ge -1, z \le 1, z\ge -1\}$$ Do you think you can figure out matrices $A, B$ that encode those inequalities? (Note that the matrices do not have to be square.) Once you figure that out, it should be clearer which way to proceed for more complicated cases. If not, try to do the same for a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that a polyhedron is the set of points satisfying an inequality of the type
$$
Cx \le b
$$
where $C$ is a matrix, $b$ a vector. Let $c_i$ be the $i$-th row of $C$.

Since $0\in P$, it follows $b_i \ge0$. Now if $b_i=0$, then put the inequality
$c_i^Tx \le0$ into matrix $B$. If $b_i>0$, then put the inequality $c_i^Tx\le b_i$ in the form $(b_i^{-1}c_i^T)x \le 1$ into matrix $A$.